# How to search by date with Grails searchable plugin

Tags: groovy, grails-plugin, searchable-plugin

I am using the searchable plugin for Grails and I am wondering how I can search by date?

My groovy class has a date field like this

```
class Foo {
    Date myDate
    String value

    static searchable = true
}
```

and I am able to search for things in the value field but not in the date field.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809428/grails-lucene-compass-query-builder-and-date-ranges

Comment: @aldrin ahh thanks too simple