# Empty result set from a Compass Lucene query with Dates

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, search-engine, compass-lucene

I am using Compass to make queries on data inside in memory data structure. It works fine for searching String and enum values, now I want to search dates.

Search criteria are annotated by `@SearchRestriction` annotation. Example about someDate:

```
    @SearchRestriction(path="fooBar.someDate" type = SearchRestrictionType.EQUAL)
    String someDate;
```

At searchable data SomeDate is annotated like the following:

```
    @SearchableProperty
    Date someDate;
```

`SomeDate` inside the searchable data is generated with `new Date();`) and query String is given as `20120802`.

**Situation on debugger:**
This code generates queries like this:

```
    someDate:20120802
```

Here `someDate` is the name of the field I am looking for and `20120802` is a date in order yyyyMMdd.

**Problem:**
No results is returned, when this query is run. I get an empty list. The Date in query is the same as in the Date object.

**What is wrong??**
Is this wrong way to search `Date`s with Compass? I can find only range queries about Date, but a search with exact Date or part of exact Date I cannot find.

Comment: [http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/DateTools.html) tells how Date can be converted to String for indexing. Should this mean my @SearchableProperty should go on a String formed with DateTools? And then it works?

Comment: I believe there is a way to go with Date objects but I have to be missing something crusial? Anybody has made queries with Dates?

Comment: I have never used compass API but what I do know is all annotation based framework use reflection so value printed in the logs may not be used while comparison is being done. The annotation should specify way to convert date object to string. I will advice you to look by this perspective.

Comment: Thanks Amit. Actually `someDate:20120802` is the real query String that is lured from that String variable by debugging the program. It really uses that String to pass to the engine for search. It is not just a log entry.

Comment: Well, you pointed to the right direction. This is what I found based on your comment: http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.0.0M2/reference/html/core-osem.html . I should tell the format of Date with `@SearchableProperty(format = "yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: Great :) Happy to see solution is what I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the format for Searchable property [Date]

```
@SearchableProperty(format = "yyyyMMdd")
```

To some extent, it relates to [Grails: Lucene, Compass Query Builder and date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809428/grails-lucene-compass-query-builder-and-date-ranges)